# Is there a specific reason why a trailing-return-type is not a complete-class context of a class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Note that a *trailing-return-type* is not mentioned in [[class.mem]p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6)

> A complete-class context of a class is a
>
> (6.1) function body,
> (6.2) default argument,
> (6.3) noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]),
> (6.4) contract condition, or
> (6.5) default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class. [ Note: A complete-class
> context of a nested class is also a complete-class context of any
> enclosing class, if the nested class is defined within the
> member-specification of the enclosing class. — end note ]

[[expr.prim.this]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#this-2) also has a note about this:

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function
> template of a class X, the expression this is a prvalue of type
> “pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifier-seq
> and the end of the function-definition, member-declarator, or
> declarator. It shall not appear before the optional cv-qualifier-seq
> and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member
> function (although its type and value category are defined within a
> static member function as they are within a non-static member
> function). [ Note: This is because declaration matching does not occur
> until the complete declarator is known. — end note ] [ Note: **In a
> trailing-return-type, the class being defined is not required to be
> complete for purposes of class member access. Class members declared
> later are not visible.** [ Example: ...

Comment: Only a guess: the _trailing-return-type_ needs to be interpreted before the class is fully declared. On the other hand, a function body, a default argument, etc. are interpreted after the class has been declared and while it is defined.

Comment: if it were, the following would be possible: `struct A {  auto f() -> decltype(member) { return {}; } int member; };` But this would mess with the way compilers work as `member` is declared only after `f` is. (still a guess)

Comment: though `struct A { auto f() { return member; } int member; };` is legal... go figure!

Comment: @YSC But the same argument would have to be applied to a _noexcept-specififer_, which is a _complete-class context_ of a class.

Comment: That's true. I really don't know. Waiting some guru to answer :)

Comment: Just a super wild guess: The left hand return type isn't in the context either, and when trailing-return-type was proposed, they wanted to impose minimal changes for implementations to support it.

Comment: for `auto` not to perform automatic type deduction.

Comment: @YSC: but then `auto bar() -> decltype(this->f())` is not possible [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1WGhPP).

Comment: @Jarod42 when `f` is declared with a placeholder return type, yes. I don't get how it connects with what I wrote though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you don't want it.

```
 struct Test {
     auto foo() -> decltype(bar());
     auto bar() -> int;

     auto baz() -> decltype(qux());
     auto qux() -> decltype(baz());
 };
```

Now you need all sorts of rules explaining which of the above is allowed and which is not.

So why does the standard places *noexcept-specifier* in *complete-class context*? Wouldn't it allow essentially the same thing in code like this:

```
struct Test { 
    void foo() noexcept(noexcept(bar())); 
    void bar() noexcept(noexcept(foo())); 
};
```

?

It seems the standard doesn't address this well, and the compilers differ in treatment of this. Clang complains about the above code, but eats this:

```
struct Test { 
    void foo() noexcept(Test::b);
    static const bool b = true;
};
```

GCC complains about the second code too, but accepts code with the member declarations swapped. It seems it doesn't treat the noexcept specifier as complete-class context at all.

Comment: What all sorts of rules would one need?  If they just add that a trailing return is part of the completed context then you know it will work just like `struct test { auto foo() { return bar(); } auto bar() { return 42; } };` does.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem is not between `foo` and `bar`, but between `baz` and `qux`.

Comment: Well... we have it for _noexcept-specifier_, don't we? https://godbolt.org/z/VUL6V4

Comment: BTW, gcc trunk [rejects `struct Test { void foo() noexcept(noexcept(bar())); void bar() noexcept; };`](https://godbolt.org/z/1az7Qe). bug?

Comment: No I absolutely don't know how it would work. Short of building a name dependency graph, verifying that it's acyclic, and proceeding top to bottom, it is not possible to even think of how this could be interpreted. Your example doesn't need any such thing, all function bodies are just processed after everything else in the class.

Comment: @YSC In an exception specification of baz you can refer to qux but not its exception specification, so recursion is still not allowed. I'll update the answer with this info.

Comment: @YSC no I think I'm mistaken, I cannot find this in the standard. g++ and clang differ in treatment of these things.

Comment: Wouldn't `qux` and `baz` be "use of auto before deducing it's type" or something even if it is in the complete class context?

Comment: @PsserBy complete-class context is called complete because in it the class is a complete type. In particular this means tyes of its members are all known and usable. There is no problem to use `qux` in any member function *body*, defined before or after `qux`. This is why function bodies are complete-class contexts. Trailing return types don't behave the same way.

Comment: The self-referential issue for `noexcept` is noted in core issue [361](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#361).