# Is getting the decltype of a deduced member function inside the trailing return type of another member function well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Whoever is saying that this question is a duplicate of the question "[Is there a specific reason why a trailing-return-type is not a complete-class context of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767088/1042389)" does not know what he/she is talking about. The fact that a trailing return type is not a complete-class context of a class does **not** explain why the code in this question doesn't compile, although it explains the rejection of the code given in the answer to the other question, specially the part of the code involving the member functions `qux` and `baz`, as explained by the OP.

In order to clarify my argument that the code below is valid, you have to take into consideration [the second note](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#this-2.note-2) in [expr.prim.this] which says: **In a trailing-return-type, the class being defined is not required to be complete for purposes of class member access. Class members declared later are not visible.** As `foo` is declared before `bar` in my example, there is nothing to prevent the compiler from accessing `foo` in the trailing-return-type of `bar`.

<strike>Note that [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795238/the-following-code-doesnt-compile-but-it-should-according-to-dcl-spec-auto-9#comment96369076_54795238) by @NathanOliver is based on the conjecture that the inline definition for the member function `foo` below is just syntactic sugar. This needs to be proven from a quote in the Standard. **I haven't found that yet**. Once that quote is produced, I will certainly accept an answer arguing that the code doesn't compile because a trailing-return-type is not a complete-class context of a class.</strike>

```
struct Test {
        auto foo() {}                       
        auto bar() -> decltype(foo()) {}
    };

prog.cc:3:32: error: use of 'auto Test::foo()' before deduction of 'auto'
    3 |     auto bar() -> decltype(foo()) {}
      |                                ^
prog.cc:3:32: error: use of 'auto Test::foo()' before deduction of 'auto'
```

[[dcl.spec.auto]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#9):

> If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type
>   has no non-discarded return statements, the return type is deduced as
>   though from a return statement with no operand at the closing brace of
>   the function body. [ Example:
>
> `auto  f() { }                   // OK, return type is void`
>
> `auto* g() { }                   // error, cannot deduce auto* from void()`
>
> — end example ]

[[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/(2.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#2.1):

> A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding
>   initializer `e`, are determined as follows:
>
> (2.1) for a non-discarded
>   return statement that occurs in a function declared with a return type
>   that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the declared return type and `e`
>   is the operand of the return statement. **If the return statement has no
>   operand, then `e` is `void()`**;
>
> (2.2) for a variable declared with a
>   type that contains a placeholder type, T is the declared type of the
>   variable and e is the initializer. If the initialization is
>   direct-list-initialization, the initializer shall be a
>   braced-init-list containing only a single assignment-expression and e
>   is the assignment-expression;
>
> (2.3) for a non-type template
>   parameter declared with a type that contains a placeholder type, T is
>   the declared type of the non-type template parameter and e is the
>   corresponding template argument.

According to [dcl.spec.auto]/9 and [dcl.type.auto.deduct]/(2.1) the code should compile. But [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nBmb8YD6nukBOb90#result-container-tab-5) and cland reject it. What am I missing?

Comment: From a logical standpoint, consider that `bar` is usable in `foo`'s body, but for `bar` to be usable by then, its declaration must be known before `foo`'s body.

Comment: @chris `foo`s body is empty, its not doing anything and returning `void` the definitions are given for both

Comment: @user463035818, I said usable, not that it is currently used.

Comment: @chris have to admit i dont really understand, read your comment already several times, still trying

Comment: @user463035818, Imagine you're writing a compiler. If the language takes whether you *use* `bar` into account, then resolving `bar`'s declaration requires looking through all of its dependencies and seeing if any of their definitions use any part of `bar`, introducing a cycle. It's much more complex (and possibly not doable in general, I don't know), increases compilation time, and causes changes in a *definition* to affect whether another *declaration* compiles.

Comment: @chris you mean in general it is impossible to decude one methods return type based on another methods return type when the second is declared to return `auto` ?

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to parse through the standard but what I suspect is happening here is the function body of a inline member function definition is just syntactic sugar.  It is really treated like it was declared, and the function body is outside the class.  This means that in the trailing return type we can't know what the return will be yet since the class/function isn't complete.

Comment: @user463035818, It's not super straightforward because `auto` on  its own without the trailing type still [catches problems](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mmqzc9) (sorry, messed up the initial link). However, leaving the return type deduced allows marking the return type as "unknown" or similar in this pass, left to be resolved later when all the symbols and their initial types are known. Using `foo` in the return type would require going through `foo`'s body *right now*, before that initial pass is done. Or it would require identifying problematic cases this early.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nevetheless `foo` is declared before `bar` and by [\[expr.prim.this\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#this-2), `foo` is visible in `bar`'s _trailing-return-type_.

Comment: @Ayrosa Yes, the name foo is accessible, but what it returns has not yet been established as that comes from looking at its function body and I believe that happens after the class is complete (the ending semicolon).

Comment: It comes down to what is the complete class context I believe.  http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a specific reason why a trailing-return-type is not a complete-class context of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767088/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-a-trailing-return-type-is-not-a-complete-class-co)

Comment: ^That. Not exactly a dupe, but answers your question.

Comment: @PasserBy No it doesn't. See my comments above.

Comment: "Whoever is saying that this question is a duplicate of the question does not know what he/she is talking about..." Wrong.  Sasha does know, just hasn't bothered to explain it to you.  I hope my answer fills in the missing piece in your understanding.

Comment: Why do you need a quote? Are you going to take the standard committee to a court of law and argue on technicalities? The intent is clear as day. If the wording contradicts the intent, then there's a defect anf you are welcome to file one.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The class is incomplete in the return type, but you have access to `foo()` according to the second Note in [\[expr.prim.this\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#2).

Comment: @Ayrosa yes you are right, sorry

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> struct Test
> {
>     auto foo() { /*1*/ }                       
>     auto bar() -> decltype(foo()) {}
> };
> ```

At marker 1, the name `Test::bar` is in scope along with all other members of `struct Test`.  Therefore the compiler cannot analyze the body of `foo()` until the class is complete.

We then have a partial ordering:

- Parse body of `Test::foo()` before deducing its return type
- Complete class `Test` before parsing body of `Test::foo()`
- Analyze trailing return type of `Test::bar()` before completing class `Test` (from the question you pled is not a dupe)

and by transitivity, the return type of `Test::bar()` must be analyzed without yet performing return type deduction for `Test::foo()`.

---

Since a Standard quote was requested, here it is from `[class.mem]`:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, **the class is regarded as complete within function bodies**, default arguments, *noexcept-specifiers*, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

Comment: "Therefore the compiler cannot evaluate the body of `foo()` until the class is complete". This doesn't make any sense to me, could you clarify?