# Derived-to-base conversion for incomplete types required by decltype

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, decltype

I came across this code snipped involving trailing return types and inheritance.

The following minimal example compiles fine with g++, not with clang

```
struct Base {};

int foo(Base&) {
    return 42;
}

struct Derived : public Base {
    auto bar() -> decltype(foo(*this)) {
        return foo(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    derived.bar();  

    return 0;
}
```

However, if we change `auto bar() -> decltype(foo(*this))` to `decltype(auto) bar()` (c++14 extension), the code compiles also with clang. Link to godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/qf_k6X .

Can anyone explain me

- how `auto bar() -> decltype(return expression)` differs from `decltype(auto) bar()`
- why the behavior between compilers differs
- what the right implementation is?

Comment: A bug in a major compiler is a great first question!

Comment: Thanks @Kerndog73 . Interestingly enough, also MVSC and ICC succeed to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gcc bug, the trailing return type isn't within a *complete-class context* [[class.mem]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#6)

> A complete-class context of a class is a
>
> - function body,
> - default argument,
> - noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]),
> - contract condition, or
> - default member initializer

We see that a complete class is needed for the derived to base conversion from [[conv.ptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr#3)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a **complete class type**, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class of D.

and [[dcl.init.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.ref#4)

> “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” if a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T2” can be converted to the type “pointer to cv1 T1” via a standard conversion sequence. In all cases where the reference-compatible relationship of two types is used to establish the validity of a reference binding and the standard conversion sequence would be ill-formed, a program that necessitates such a binding is ill-formed.

On the other hand, a function body is within a *complete-class context* and thus the derived to base conversion is well-formed. The return type involving a placeholder type (`decltype(auto)`) [is valid](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.spec.auto-11) as long as it is already deduced before an expression using it.

For a possible workaround in C++11, you may use

```
auto bar() -> decltype(foo(std::declval<Base&>()))
{
    return foo(*this);
}
```

provided you know that you want to call it with `Base`.

Comment: This just made me wonder: Is this simply an oversight or is there a particular reason why this should not work? If there is a reason this should not work, then why is it allowed in a noexcept specifier which, since C++17, is just as much part of the type of the function as the return type!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767088/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-a-trailing-return-type-is-not-a-complete-class-co

Comment: @PasserBy thanks for the pointer. So it does seem that that's kinda a defect in the standard…!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Most likely for the `noexcept` case, yes.

Comment: Then how are covariant return types of the same class expected to compile?

Comment: Do you mean `Derived& f();`? Forming the reference is legal, just not having it be converted. Converting within the function body is also allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think Clang is wrong to reject this:

Regarding the return type of a function definition, the C++14 standard says this:

[**`[dcl.fct]/9]`**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct#9)

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for
>   a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type (possibly cv-qualified) unless the function is deleted (8.4.3) **or the definition is nested within the member-specification for that class** (including definitions
>   in nested classes defined within the class).

In your example the definition of `bar` is nested within the member-specification of the `class Derived`. So this is allowed and GCC, ICC and MSVC get this right.

On the other hand `decltype(auto)` works because a deduced return type is not actually deduced until the signature of the function is needed.
And in your case, this happens when you call `bar()` in `main`. At that point of time the `class Derived` is a completely defined type. Clang gets this right.

Note that even using `auto` instead of `decltype(auto)` will work for your example. See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Hwpa0P) on godbolt.

Comment: Your bolded sentence applies to `struct A { A f(); };`, not that the class is complete at that point.

Comment: @PasserBy: The class is not complete. But the definition of `bar` (and not just its declaration) is nested within the member specification. Actually the quote from `[class.mem]/2` is not needed. Just thought it would be a good to include the quote. Do you think it is distracting?

Comment: I meant, that bolded sentence doesn't make the class complete at the nested definition, it just allows for the specific case of returning the incomplete class. The declaration is still not in a complete class context.

Comment: @PasserBy: Yes, I agree. I think the second quote causes the misunderstanding as people will think that I am saying that the class is complete at that point. I have removed it.