# Incomplete types in member function definitions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[dcl.fct.def] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-2.sentence-3) states:

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete or abstract (possibly cv-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted.

And [[class.mem] p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-7) states:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. The class is regarded as complete within its complete-class contexts; otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

Given this code:

```
struct S
{
  // S is incomplete
  S f() {  /* S is complete in a function body */ return S(); }
  // S is incomplete 
};
// S is complete
```

A [complete-class context](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6) notably does not include the decl-specifier-seq of the function definition, nor does it include the declarator of the function, however, every compiler says this is ok. What wording allows this, as I cannot find it?

Comment: I think it's quite clear what "The class is regarded as complete within its complete-class contexts" means.

Comment: @NeilButterworth if you look at the definition of what a complete-class context is http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6 only the function body is included.

Comment: @NeilButterworth But in [*complete-class contexts*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6) the function definition is not included, and that contains the *decl-specifier-seq*

Comment: What's the question

Comment: @nicomp What is the wording that permits using the type of the class being defined in the decl-specifier-seq and declarator of a function definition.

Comment: And in this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/Loa0eU) `S` is incomplete again :) Seems like an oversight to me, `S` should be incomplete in the return type except when using it directly like you are.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Why not just make the entire function-definition a complete class context? Its considered to be complete in a functions noexcept-specifier (which needs to have the full class definition anyways to perform overload resolution), so why not the return type and parameters? https://godbolt.org/z/sQxSno

Comment: @KrystianS The current definition of complete-class context is already pain in the butt because it is unclear how to treat self-referential `noexcept`s. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767417/9585016 and [CWG361](http://wg21.link/cwg361).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So what should be done? Open a defect report?

Comment: @KrystianS IDK. Maybe.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'll do so and update once it gets assigned a number.

Comment: If you [split the defintion from the declaration](https://godbolt.org/z/o92aYO), it should be ok, but still fails on gcc.  Seems like a gcc bug?

Comment: @KrystianS you didn't update...

Answer (score 7):

The very first item at the referred to link:

> A complete-class context of a class is a
>
> - function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),

So within the function body of any method is considered a complete-class context.  The "context of a function definition" is synonymous with the function body, as far as I can tell -- as opposed to the context of a function declaration, where the return type is not required to be complete.

Comment: No, the context of the function definition is the *member-specification*. Furthermore, the function body does not include the return type or parameters of the function, see http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-1.sentence-2

Comment: @KrystianS: that's the context of the function declaration, not the function definition...

Comment: No, the definition appears in the *member-specification*, therefore the context of the function definition is the *member-specification*

Comment: But the definition itself is just the body -- the rest is the declaration.

Comment: No, a declaration can be a definition, and is if the function-body is provided, see http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2. Furthermore, with your interpretation, this would be well formed: https://godbolt.org/z/L6TINp

Comment: @KrystianS Confusing though the wording may be, [dcl.fct.def]/2 means to say that the completeness of the type is checked from within the function body; see [CWG1824](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1824).

Comment: @bogdan Ah, ok. While the intent is there, the wording does not accomplish what it intends to (perhaps it would be more appropriate to say "within the *function-body*")

Comment: @KrystianS In godbolt.org/z/L6TINp, `S` in the return type and `struct S {};` in the function body are 2 different types.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the compiler first finds tokens [lex.phases 1.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.7) `S` class (with all of its members declared) and `f` member function (with just declaration, which includes the return type). Then, they are analyzed.

By the time the function body of `f` is analyzed the `S` class was analyzed first and considered as complete, because it has the member-function defined (the function boby is there, will be analyzed later).

Now `S` is complete, `f` can use `return S()`.

---

But it his other case:

```
struct S {
    decltype(S{}) f() { return S(); }
};
```

the compiler wants to find the type of `S` by `decltype` so as to regard the token (the return type of `f`) and fails because the `};` class-ending is not reached yet.

Comment: That wording still does not make the return type or parameters of a function a complete-class context though.

Comment: In the 'other' case, if you move the function definition after closing `}`, gcc [still fails](https://godbolt.org/z/o92aYO), so this seems like a gcc bug

Comment: @ChrisDodd I don't think so. Gcc complains because of the reason I told, not because the body of the function.