# why a class type is considers as complete type when the its name appears as the return type of a member function that in the definition of such class

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct Test{
  Test show(){
    return Test{};
  }
  int a;
};
```

Consider the above code , The return type of a function shall be a complete type, because of this:
[dcl.fct#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#11)

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition **shall not be an incomplete (possibly cv-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition** unless the function is deleted.

The type `Test` is used as the return type of function `show`, which is defined within the definition of class `Test`. However according to the standard, the class type `Test` is considered as incomplete type at that point, because of this:
[class.mem#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#6)

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier. Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as **complete** within **function bodies**, **default arguments**, **noexcept-specifiers**, and **default member initializers** (including such things in nested classes). **Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification**.

The member function show is not `deleted`, and it is defined within the definition of class `Test`. The `return type` satisfies none of the quote says what as I have emphasized for. At this point, the return type shall be an incomplete type. However the compiler consider the code as [well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/sz379q)

As a opposite:

```cpp
struct B;
struct Test{
  B show(){
  }
  int a;
};
```

the compiler will give an explicitly [error](https://godbolt.org/z/henTe8)
notice that denotes the return type `B` is incomplete. It's in accordance with the rules.

why compilers consider the first example as a well-formed code? It it a bug?  If I miss anything special rule regarding such case, please point it out.

Comment: Would not a more equivalent  test use  `struct Test{   B show(){` --> `struct Test{   Test show(){`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  Such example would be equivalent in essence(since the return type are all incomplete type), however the compiler result is not the same. My question is why the complier consider struct Test{   Test show(){}}; as a well-formed code?

Comment: IIUC «in the context of the function definition» means «in the function body». I.e. [dcl.fct]/11 says: «The return type shall not be a type which won't be [considered] complete in the body of the function». And in the body of a member function defined inside its own class, the type of that class considered complete.

Comment: Kinda dup of [Incomplete types in member function definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631441/incomplete-types-in-member-function-definitions)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer where's the quote implies that the `in the context of the function definition` refers to `in the body of function definition`? I only find [dcl.fct.def#general-1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#general-1)

Comment: [Here](http://wg21.link/cwg1824)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think `in the context of the function definition` is not clear if there's no interpretation such as in the link you cited. I think `in the context of the function's body` is more better.

Comment: @jackX Agree, that the wording could be improved. File an editorial issue, if you want.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I would  but there's no any similar quote in the [latest standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct)

Comment: The wording has been moved and, turns out, already fixed https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-2.sentence-3

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I have seen. The current quote is clear.

Comment: The CWG issue was submitted by the author of the question linked above

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I traced it out, namely [CWG2430](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1968r0.html#2430)

Comment: I voted to close this question because the issue it brings up has already been fixed.