# what is difference between "using type" syntax in specific method and in general class?

Tags: c++, syntax, using

```
template<class Derived>
class Base{
    public:
        using dType = typename Derived::Type; //1
        void interface(){
            using dType = typename Derived::Type; //2
        }
};
template<typename T>
class Derived:public Base<Derived<T>>{
    public:
        using Type = T;
};

int main(){
    Base<Derived<int>>{};
    return 0;
}
```

When I use 'using' syntax in (1), I got errors like

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'class Derived<int>':
test.cpp:14:9:   required from 'class Base<Derived<int> >'
test.cpp:31:21:   required from here
test.cpp:23:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Base<Derived<int> >'
   23 | class Derived:public Base<Derived<T>>{
      |       ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:12:7: note: declaration of 'class Base<Derived<int> >'
   12 | class Base{
      |
```

But, when I use it in (2), I have no error.
What is difference them?

Comment: Seems likely to be related to whether or not you're in a [complete-class context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767088/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-a-trailing-return-type-is-not-a-complete-class-co). Not sure where the best explanation of that is.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions instantiate later in the process, when the class itself is fully defined.  (Because member functions of class templates are only instantiated if they are actually used, and they can only be used on complete types, or instances of those types) and for that to happen, the class must be a complete type.

However, while Base is being instantiated, Derived itself is an incomplete type (since a base class must be instantiated before a derived class can determine its layout), so inside Base, it cannot look into Derived because Derived is incomplete.  It simply is looking into its template type too early for it to be valid.

Comment: So, if I want to use derived template type in Base, do I just use full type, Derived::Type, or redefine every method?